# Proper way to uniquely identify a message sent via XMPP in delegate method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am writing an iOS chat application using XMPPFramework, and I am wondering what's the best way to create a new message so I can map the `XMPPMessage` that gets returned in one of the delegate methods back to the original message that is sent.  I want to do this so I can tell when sending a message is successful or unsuccessful (so I can cache and resend it).

Upon the user hitting the send key on the client, the following code is called to create and send the message:

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:messageText];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:recipientJID];
[message addChild:body];

[[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

Then I store the contents, recipient, timestamp, etc. into a custom object (basically everything in `message`) in an array.

I want to be able to match an object in the array to the `XMPPMessage` object returned in either of these delegate methods:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didFailToSendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didSendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

}
```

Is there an attribute that I can add some kind of unique identifier to in the `message` variable that I send via `XMPPStream` that will then show up within the `XMPPMessage` passed to those delegate methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you send a `XMPPMessage` instead of a `NSXMLElement`? That way the object passed in `didFailToSendMessage` and `didSendMessage` will match the one you send. Besides, you can set `elementId` to identify stanzas (Messages, IQs or Presence)

```
XMPPMessage *message = [XMPPMessage messageWithType:@"chat"
                                                 to:someJid
                                          elementID:elementId];

[[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

Comment: Good point on passing XMPPMessage initially.  Just running it through the debugger last night, I noticed that the XMPPMessage in one of those delegate messages contained the same value for the name property as the NSXMLElement I originally sent.  To your knowledge, is there any different pros/ cons between using name or elementID for uniquely identifying stanzas on the client side, or are they both available for any sort of client-side use?

Comment: You should definitely use elementId.This is the "id" attribute in XMPP stanzas, and can not only be used by your client but by the server or other clients. For example to discard duplicate stanzas, or to identify which IQ result corresponds to an IQ set/get.

Comment: I could not understand.Please provide source code Thanks @MatíasR